# Service needed to add a tankless water heater

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, water-heater, subpanel, tankless

I am currently building a detached 250 sq feet studio in my backyard. The studio will have a tiny bathroom with a tankless water heater, a baseboard heater, and a few lights, a mini split (ac), of course a few plugs and switches. The electrical will come from the main box on our house. The current box is rated 150 Amps. We will get a service upgrade to 200 amps, a new 200 amp box and a sub panel of 100 amp. The sub panel will feed the studio. 
Here are the specs if what will ge in the studio: 
Tankless water heater, 60 amps, 240v
Baseboard heater 20 amps, 
Mini split 20 amps, 220v
Lights, switches,
Potientially a ceiling fan

The question is, if i currently have 150amps, will the service upgrade to 200 amps with a 100 amp sub panel be sufficient to feed the right power the studio?

I appreciate your insights.

Comment: How many square feet is your current house, how many kitchen receptacle branch circuits does it have, and what do you have for an HVAC system + other large appliances (dryer, water heater, range/stove) there?